# Using JavaMail to read mail from my web mail account (such as Yahoo or Hotmail)?

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I can get mails, receipient mail id's etc. using mail api in android but from only gmail. I want to get details of all accounts like yahoo, outlook, hotmail etc. what are the host, mail store type and folder names of these accounts. For example

Gmail

```
String host="imap.gmail.com";
String mailStoreType="imaps";
Folder folderName=store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking...

If you're asking how to access those other mail services once you have all the configuration information, the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) has lots of examples.

If you're asking how to discover all that configuration information that may already be set up in the android mail application, I don't know...